# Sorting by nested dictionary in Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I have below structure

```
{
    'searchResult' : [{
            'resultType' : 'station',
            'ranking' : 0.5
        }, {
            'resultType' : 'station',
            'ranking' : 0.35
        }, {
            'resultType' : 'station',
            'ranking' : 0.40
        }
    ]
}
```

and want to get

```
{
    'searchResult' : [{
            'resultType' : 'station',
            'ranking' : 0.5
        }, {
            'resultType' : 'station',
            'ranking' : 0.4
        }, {
            'resultType' : 'station',
            'ranking' : 0.35
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried the code without success

```
result = sorted(result.items(), key=lambda k: k[1][0][1]["ranking"], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks all! But which method is faster `d["item"].sort()` or `sorted()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: @SpanishBoy `sorted` returns a new object. If you don't need the original object you'd better stick with `sort` for speed and memory efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are okay with changing the objects in-place.

```
a = {
    'searchResult' : [{
                       'resultType' : 'station',
                       'ranking' : 0.5
                      }, {
                       'resultType' : 'station',
                       'ranking' : 0.35
                      }, {
                      'resultType' : 'station',
                      'ranking' : 0.40
                      }]
  }

a["searchResult"].sort(key=lambda d: d["ranking"], reverse=True)
```

Or you can make a deep copy to keep the original

```
from copy import deepcopy


srt_dict = deepcopy(a)
srt_dict["searchResult"].sort(key=lambda d: d["ranking"], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do an inplace sort on the list, using `key=itemgetter("ranking")` and `reverse=True`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
d["searchResult"].sort(key=itemgetter("ranking"),reverse=True)

print(d)
{'searchResult': [{'resultType': 'station', 'ranking': 0.5}, {'resultType': 'station', 'ranking': 0.4}, {'resultType': 'station', 'ranking': 0.35}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just sort the list and write over itself in the dictionary.

```
result = {
    'searchResult' : [{
            'resultType' : 'station',
            'ranking' : 0.5
        }, {
            'resultType' : 'station',
            'ranking' : 0.35
        }, {
            'resultType' : 'station',
            'ranking' : 0.40
        }
    ]
}

result['searchResult'] = sorted(result['searchResult'], key= lambda x: x['ranking'], reverse=True)
```